# Is it possible to write a CLI that plays music from Soundcloud without opening Soundcloud visually (in a browser)?

Tags: node.js, audio, command-line-interface, soundcloud

So I want to code a CLI in which you can put a playlist of soundcloud songs together. I want to play the music inside the terminal (cli), so it shouldn't just open the browser and put the URL in. Is there any possible approach to that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soundcloud [API reference](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#streaming) says:

> Yep, you can also play sounds from your application.Depending on your needs, you can embed a player widget, use the JavaScript SDK to stream audio content in the browser, **or feed a stream url into your own audio player**.

I think that's what you want.

- Use the API to retrieve the URL
- Pass the URL to a CLI player

Answer (score 0):

Here's a post that provides various methods to play audio from the command line (once you've retrieved it via Soundcloud's API).

https://askubuntu.com/questions/115369/how-to-play-mp3-files-from-the-command-line

I'm not sure whether Soundcloud can stream MP3s, but the examples should still prove useful.